# Meshlab STL export

Tags: export

I am trying to export STL data modified in MeshLab and then open the STL file in CREO parametric. However CREO cannot see the exported STL file, therefore I can't open it. The original file can be opened in CREO, can you recommend certain export settings?

Answer (score 0):

If yout STL file is too complex, you cannot open it with Creo.
One method is to convert your STL to STEP format file. For some complex stl file,it is very hard to do that.

Comment: Adding how to do the conversion would help your answer.